# Connecting to server through SSH, disconnects outbound Cisco AnyConnect VPN on the same server

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, vpn

I have a server that hosts several front ends and APIs, and these APIs need AnyConnect VPN to be able to get access to a remote database.
For the last 2 weeks though (**After a complete server restart I suspect**) when I connect to my server by SSH, this VPN is disconnected and needs to be manually reconnected, which causes disruptions with the API's and has been bringing a lot of downtime. Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

I know for a fact that before these last 2 weeks, connecting to the server through SSH was fine and caused no issues with the VPN connection. The only cause I can think of, is that because the connection has been up for months on end, maybe after a reconnect, it did auto updates that changed some settings that created this SSH issue, or that the server restart changed something related to IP routing

The syslog at var/log/syslog shows the following after I connect with ssh:

> E4CA10B acvpnagent[798]: Termination reason code 5: The user is
> logging off the system.
> E4CA10B acvpnagent[798]: Function:
> OnTunnelStateChange File: ../../vpn/Agent/TND.cpp Line: 2053 tunnel
> state change notification (new 3, old 1)
> E4CA10B acvpnagent[798]: The
> Primary DTLS connection to the secure gateway is being torn down.

So apparently connecting to the server via ssh is being detected as a user logging off the system which causes the VPN to shut down. Anyone has a clue as to why and how to fix this?